# Creating a Database Connection Object

Tags: php, database, mysqli, global-variables, database-connection

For my web application, I am using mySQLi instead of PDO.

Currently, I realised that I am creating a database connection whenever I require it.  Be it during login, registration etc.

Is there a way where I create a global variable that connects to my database once and for all?  So that when I were to change the database server, I need to search through all my codes to change all the database parameters such as its server, username, password etc?

Comment: yes, there is a way to create a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is really to create an object $db that you use everywhere.

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

You are then able to use this everywhere. In functions for example you have to access it with the `global` keyword.

```
function dbUtf8(){
  global $db;
  $db->query(" SET NAMES 'utf8' ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that I initialise this global variable from the moment the user access my login/ registration page at my loginscript, say loginscript.php?  And when the session is alive, regardless of any pages it goes within my site, I can call onto the variable $db?  Or the variable is only accessible within the same php page?

Comment: This variable is only available in the scope of the page it is declared in. You can include this file in every other page though.

Comment: I can create a separate php page and named it as database_cxn.php.  Inside, my codes can include:

    global $db;
    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

And then in every page that requires a database connection, I can do this:

    include_once "/common/database_cxn.php";

And whenever I needed to query, i just do something like this:

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sqlquery);

Am i right?

Comment: @Madwolf I did not understand that you use the procedural way. Then you have to do it slightly different:

database_cxn.php:
`$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

other files:
`include_once "/common/database_cxn.php";`
`$result = mysqli_query($db,$sqlquery);`

Comment: Great!Thanks for your tip and help!